# API Controller Post method return type/value

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api2, .net-4.5, asp.net-apicontroller

I want to use a .NET Web API 2 Controller for my vb.net game.

I added one to my project and I updated my Global.axax.vb & Application_Start method per the instructions.

Right now I'm just trying to figure out how it works.

But I don't know what to return or how to return with my Controller method.

This is my test ajax method:

```
<script>
    $("#btnUpdate").click(function(e) {

        var Data = {};
        Data.test1 = "testVal1";
        Data.test2 = "testVal2";

        $.ajax({
            url: 'api/GameData',
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: Data,
            success: function(data) {
                alert("Saved successfully");
            },
            fail: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert("Request failed: " + textStatus);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my empty PostValue method that Visual Studio generated:

```
    ' POST: api/GameData
    Public Sub PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal value As String)
        'what type of return value?
    End Sub
```

What should this method return?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on scenario it can return one of following

1. void --> http response will be 204
2. HttpResponseMessage
3. IHttpActionResult
4. Serialized return body for http reponse 200

Generally, Http POST api return 201 created with resource created. Example

```
Public Function PostValue(<FromBody> value As String) As IHttpActionResult
    Dim product = New With {Key .Name = "Watch", .Price = 250}
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.Created, product, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
End Function
```

For details will example

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.ihttpactionresult(v=vs.118).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 3):

Let's assess the generated code first. Your handler for the post request is indicated by the name PostValue. Without using any attributes such as ActionName or AcceptVerbs your methods selection is based on it's naming convention. PostValue is a Post method for obvious reasons. A GetValue would be a Get method. I prefer the ActionName attribute to make more specific api calls.

```
' POST: api/GameData
<ActionName("GameData")>
Public Sub PostGameData(<FromBody()> ByVal value As String)
    'what type of return value?
End Sub
```

With the very basic routing setup you can now access this call via "api/GameData" with a POST request. Now we need to talk about retrieving that data. Typically if it's a Get request you would be sending data through the URI.

```
http://mywebsite.com/home.aspx?give=me&data=now
```

The data here is in key value pairs: give=me & data=now.

```
' Get: api/GameData
<ActionName("GameData")>
Public Function GetGameData(ByVal test1 As String, Byval test2 as String)
    'Do something with test1 and test2.
    'Return
End Function
```

If you use a post request you're sending it through the body of the request as you have done in your ajax request above. It will not be displayed in the URL.

```
' POST: api/GameData
<ActionName("GameData")>
Public Sub PostGameData(ByVal test1 As String, Byval test2 As String)
    'Do something with test1 and test2
End Sub
```

If you need to retrieve data from the url as well as from the request body you may do so by indicating before each parameter where the data is to be found.

```
' POST: api/GameData
<ActionName("GameData")>
Public Sub PostGameData(<FromURI()> ByVal name As String, <FromBody()> FormData as FormDataCollection)
    'Do something
End Sub
```

Ultimately you must understand the difference between a complex type and a simple type when it comes to Web API and it's binding of data. More in depth information is available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

You can also specify a model(object) for Web API to bind to automatically that would make this simpler but sometimes this can be too much.

```
'Model to bind to
Public Class MyData
    Public Property test1 As String
    Public Property test2 As String
End Class

'Caller Method
'POST: api/GameData
Public Sub PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal data As MyData)
    'data.test1
    'data.test2
End Sub
```

Unless overridden as shown in Kaushal's response, your return response should be in the format specified by the incoming request headers. You can send back anything you would like if working with JSON and Web API will automatically serialize it for you.

```
' POST: api/GameData
Public Function PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal value As String)
    return New MyData() With { .test1 = "Foo", .test2 = "Bar" }
End Function
```

If specified JSON this would return as:

```
{ "test1" : "Foo", "test2" : "Bar" }
```

If you wish to retrieve your form data just like you would use Request.Form.Get or Request.Querystring.Get then you could use the NameValueCollection or the FormDataCollection as a parameter model.

```
' POST: api/GameData
Public Sub PostValue(<FromBody()> ByVal value As FormDataCollection)
    'value.Get("test1")
    'value.Get("test2")
    'Do something
End Sub
```

NameValueCollection is fairly similar. Remember you will need the System.Net.Http.Formatting namespace reference if you want to use the FormDataCollection. Also do not forget to check for a null value with the FormDataCollection. Many people convert to the NameValueCollection because it does not return null only empty strings. I personally wrote an extension method for FormDataCollection called Grab that would return an empty string if the member did not exist. I suggest you take a look at the resources I have provided as well as the Microsoft documents for more in-depth explanation. I hope these quick examples can be of some use. If there are any errors in my explanation or examples please let me know! Thank you.